# How to use jitsi as an independent service on another server(own)?

Tags: open-source, video-conferencing, jitsi

I need an open source online video chat as an independent service on our server, I found jitsi.org but apparently it only runs on the jitsi's servers, I'm not sure so I'm asking that doe's any one know about it or doe's any one know another open source service to implement video chat/conference?

Answer (score 1):

You can run it on your own servers too. Just follow the installation instructions: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/quick-install.md and you should be able to get it running in no time.

Disclaimer: I work on Jitsi.

Comment: I setup local node environment and Now I added full code of this link: https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/example/example.js   now my code is working but I am not able to add others in my chat window also not able to use the function ...how I need to use this t make it working as live...I need exactly working as live..any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ saghul: Also it it possible to make it working same as live at my server....with full featured